# 'aws configure' in docker container will not use environment variables or config files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

So I have a docker container running jenkins and an EC2 registry on AWS. I would like to have jenkins push containers back to the EC2 registry.

To do this, I would like to be able to automate the `aws configure` and `get login` steps on container startup. I figured that I would be able to

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
export AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT=json
```

Which I expected to cause `aws configure` to complete automatically, but that did not work. I then tried creating configs as per the AWS docs and repeating the process, which also did not work. I then tried using `aws configure set` also with no luck.

I'm going bonkers here, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you set eval $(aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1) to ecr login set?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No real need to issue `aws configure`  instead as long as you populate env vars

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=aaaa
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=bbbb
... also export zone and region
```

then issue

```
aws ecr get-login --region ${AWS_REGION}
```

you will achieve the same desired aws login status ... as far as troubleshooting I suggest you remote login into your running container instance using

```
docker exec -ti CONTAINER_ID_HERE  bash
```

then manually issue above aws related commands interactively to confirm they run OK before putting same into your `Dockerfile`

Comment: Yeah, I'm running bash from the container now -- I think I was misunderstanding the use of aws configure. Thanks so much! I'll try this out and confirm your answer once I have it working.